# Locust stops after rapid https requests

Tags: windows, locust

Locust stops running tasks after about 1 minute.  This seems to be a new situation only on Windows and I can't easily test older configurations where it did not happen.  This happens with Locust on one server with 5 threads.  There are around 100 tasks that are HTTPS calls using FastHttpUser.  We also have Locust in another environment with the same Locust/Python versions, but running on Linux with multiple Locust servers which does not have this problem.

While there are many other configurations where Locust stops, I am able to duplicate the problem with one task and one thread that makes an HTTPS request to a server on the same subnet.  If I change to an HTTP request to the same server, make an HTTPS call to a public server, or add a wait time between calls, it will not stop prematurely.  When it stops there is no error shown and the CPU and memory on the Locust server look fine.

This is what is in the debug log.  There is a 4+ minute gap between the last HTTPS call and when Locust shuts down.

```
[2023-05-31 10:05:18,545] Locust-01/INFO/locust.runners: All users spawned: {"TestTrafficLocust": 1} (1 total users)
[2023-05-31 10:05:18,545] Locust-01/DEBUG/urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): test.localserver.com:443
[2023-05-31 10:05:20,248] Locust-01/DEBUG/urllib3.connectionpool: https://test.localserver.com:443 "GET /Check.asmx HTTP/1.1" 200 4409
[2023-05-31 10:05:20,248] Locust-01/DEBUG/urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): test.localserver.com:443
[2023-05-31 10:05:20,280] Locust-01/DEBUG/urllib3.connectionpool: https://test.localserver.com:443 "GET /Check.asmx HTTP/1.1" 200 4409
... 443 repeated calls in 14 seconds ...
[2023-05-31 10:05:34,014] Locust-01/DEBUG/urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): test.localserver.com:443
[2023-05-31 10:05:34,030] Locust-01/DEBUG/urllib3.connectionpool: https://test.localserver.com:443 "GET /Check.asmx HTTP/1.1" 200 4409
[2023-05-31 10:10:18,602] Locust-01/INFO/locust.runners: Shape test stopping
[2023-05-31 10:10:18,602] Locust-01/DEBUG/locust.runners: Stopping all users
```

I added some comments and looked at the network activity using Wireshark.  When Locust stops it gets up to the HTTPS call, but never past it.  The call is not seen using Wireshark so I do not believe it is ever made.  I have changed some timeout values, but if the call is never made there is never a return status code.  Locust never continues past that point and waits until the run time is up.

```
    print("This is printed")
    with client.get(f"https://test.localserver.com/Check.asmx", verify=False, catch_response=True, name="Test_HTTPS_Check") as healthResponse:
            
        if(healthResponse.status_code != 200):
            healthResponse.failure("This is never printed")
            return
        
    print("This is not printed")
```

This example of 445 calls in 15 seconds before it stops is not our normal test.  Our normal Locust test is more complex and stops after about 1 minute with perhaps 20 to 50 calls made.  I upgraded Locust to 2.15.1 and had the same problem, but my testing was done on this version.

locust 2.12.1
Python 3.9.0
Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0.14393 (VM)
2.36 GM RAM
Xeon Silver 4116, 6 core

It looks to me like Locust gets stuck when making too many FastHttpUser requests in a short period of time, although in our real configuration the number of requests before it stops is not that large.  The task uses network_timeout = 5.0 and connection_timeout = 5.0, but since the call is never made this does not seem to work.  Can a @task(1) have a timeout?  Any other ideas to stop Locust from stopping?  Adding a wait between tasks and increasing the threads may work if we can get the same performance out of the test.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

All of the Locust tasks were using self.client.close().  When testing with multiple IIS servers this prevented Locust from using the same IIS server over and over.  This was removed when testing against a single IIS server and Locust no longer stopped.  Locust stopping was never a problem when using many IIS servers.